# How to use suffixes and prefixes in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I am probably going start medical school next year, so I wanted to have this AutoHotkey script that would allow me to shorten prefixes and suffixes that are used all the time in the medical vocabulary. Things like hy for hyper or .n  for ation (as in "inflammation"). I already have lots of things like this:

```
::acon::congratulations
```

..but I'm at a loss about how to make it work when I need the autocompleted part (in this case a prefix or suffix) to be in the same word as the root of the word. The autocompletion usually happens when you press <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> and that would not serve for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For prefixes only:

```
:*:acon::congratulations
```

This will instantly replace the string.
For suffixes only:

```
:?:acon::congratulations
```

If you want something to work as both suffix and prefix or a prefix that comes in middle of a word:

```
:*?:acon::congratulations
```

This will work irrespective of anything.
You must choose the strings carefully though. E.g. in this case bacon will be typed as bcongratulations..

If you want more advanced stuff, go through [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm) page.

One more idea. You could limit the hotstrings only for the program in which you write your medical terms by using context sensitive hotkeys. Read more on that [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context). It talks about hotkeys. But its also applicable for hotstrings.

Comment: you certainly deserve extra points for the bacon in your answer. Now inflamma.n is inflammation with ":?:.n::ation". How do I use prefixes though?